# Use Array.length property and not a function to return length of an array by counting only distinct elements and not all elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, higher-order-functions

So I have an array like this:

items = [2, 2, 5, 3, 5, 3, 4, 7, 2, 7];

Is there a way to use items.length property here to return 5 instead of 10. I have seen a method where a function was used to get the count of the distinct elements by passing the length property as an argument. What I want to achieve is slightly different. I want the length to be printed by calling the Array.length property instead of through a function. Is it possible at all?

Here is the function:

```js
function countDistinct(arr, n) {
  let res = 1;

  // Pick all elements one by one
  for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    let j = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
      if (arr[i] === arr[j])
        break;

    // If not printed earlier, then print it
    if (i === j)
      res++;
  }
  return res;
}

// Driver program to test above function

let arr = [2, 2, 5, 3, 5, 3, 4, 7, 2, 7];
let n = arr.length;

console.log((countDistinct(arr, n)));
```

Comment: If you mean replacing `n` in your `countDistinct` function with `arr.length`, then yes - that is possible.

Comment: @AnsonMiu What I mean is if there is a way to return 5 by using `arr.length` directly instead of using the `countDistinct` function to get 5

Comment: *"I want the length to be printed by calling the Array.length property instead of through a function."* I have an array with a `length` of `20`. Can you tell me how many different values my array contains? Like, how should that work? You can do `new Set(arr).size` but that's still a function

Comment: If your function changes the `arr` and removes the duplicates, then returning `arr.length` in your function would return the length of the updated array with duplicates removed.

Comment: Alternative solution to take advantage of built-in data structures: `function countDistinct(arr) { return new Set(arr).size; }` :)

Comment: I understand now @AnsonMiu. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is barely possible, but it's really weird. If you create another object that wraps the array, you can make the `length` property a getter that deduplicates items and returns the size, something along the lines of:

```js
const makeSpecialArr = (arr) => {
  const specialArr = Object.create(arr);
  Object.defineProperty(specialArr, 'length', {
    get() {
      return new Set(arr).size;
    },
  });
  return specialArr;
};

const arr = makeSpecialArr([2, 2, 5, 3, 5, 3, 4, 7, 2, 7]);
console.log(arr.length);
```

You can't do this without creating another object around the array because an array's `.length` is an own non-configurable property.

If you wanted to do something like this, consider using a property *other* than `length`, which makes it a lot easier:

```js
const makeSpecialArr = (arr) => {
  Object.defineProperty(arr, 'dedupLength', { get() {
    return new Set(arr).size;
  }});
  return arr;
};

const arr = makeSpecialArr([2, 2, 5, 3, 5, 3, 4, 7, 2, 7]);
console.log(arr.dedupLength);
```

But even this is strange. Might be interesting as theoretical code, or for a thought experiment, but I wouldn't use it for anything serious that had to be maintained.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce for this:

```
var count = arr.reduce(function(values, v) {
   if (!values.set[v]) {
     values.set[v] = 1;
     values.count++;
   }
   return values;
}, { set: {}, count: 0 }).count;
```

Comment: I think the `Set` constructor takes care of the `arr.reduce(...)` part :)

Comment: Using set is another option available from es6. My solution is not using set data type.